# Weird material glitch in Unity5

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-glitch

Been working on a new project after moving to Unity5 and the materials are creating these weird effects. It generates a line in the mesh and causes one half to be lighter than the other.

Picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkA79.png

I'm unsure if it is because of the way the material is set up or the model, however I have checked both and reexported the model multiple times in different formats and the result seems the same.

Any help?

Comment: It looks like a problem with your lightmap have you tried adjusting the new lighting settings?

Comment: @Seph No, I'll have a look and see if there's anything wrong with them. Anything in particular I would need to enable/disable